# I cannot log in my wordpress website

Tags: wordpress

When I open my website link ,I found errors.The error is:

> "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ...../wp-includes/pomo/entry.php:2) in /...../wp-includes/pomo/pomo.php(1) : eval()'d code on line 1".

And I cannot log in my website admin that shows plugabble.php errors.
How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You need to troubleshoot whats going on...

1. Check plugin compatibility issues, deactivate plugind and see if it works
2. Another problem might be that you have gotten some text or whitespace [spaces or newline] before the opening PHP tag or after the closing PHP tag in your theme's functions.php file. There can't be a single character before or after those tags, check that...
3. Remove white spaces from other files, on wp-congig.php maybe...

Do your research on wordpress forums, the below link might help

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-4

Answer (score 0):

Its white space error or space in `< ?  ? > <? php etc.`

so check again. also as per your notice check  `includes/pomo/entry.php:2` this file and see line no 2.

if there is extra space etc then remove it.

ALso if it will not solve then open `function.php` file of theme and remove space in bottom of the page.

or last step is remove space from `wp-config` file.